# get int dat from string iterator, within a list<struct> of array

Tags: c++, string, list, iterator, stringstream

This is the homework that I encounter problem, given line of string and need to store into a list of array

Here is how I declare the list of array

```
list<terms> poly[100];
```

And here is my struct data type

```
typedef struct Node*terms;
struct Node
{
    int expo;       //exponent
    int coef;       //coefficient
}
```

Given:

```
string line = "123456"
```

I need to get the first two characters at a time and store to a struct(terms in this case) Data type
so I save '1' as token and '2' as token2. Also I need them to be int data type for later calculation. After saving them into new terms, it will loop again and read '3' and '4', convert them and save again, etc.

I've tried to use stringstream to convert but it gave me `invalid conversion from char' to const char*`

```
for ( string::iterator it=line.begin(); it!=line.end(); it++){

    int token, token2;

    //change data type from string to int
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<*it;
    ss >>token;

    stringstream ss;
    ss<<*it+1;
    ss >>token2;

    //create a new struct for current line
    struct Node* p = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    p->coef = token;
    p->expo = token2;
    poly[0].push_back(p);
}
```

Comment: That's an array of 100 lists, not list of arrays!

Comment: oops..Then this is another problem that I encounter..could you tell me what is the right format to declare array of list from range[0-99] in this case?

Comment: *shrug* I'm not even sure what you want or need, sorry. Sounds like you want to build a list of polynomials. `vector<vector<Node>>`, maybe? (`Node` should really be called `Term`, no?)

Comment: I've tried to declare like std::array<std::list<terms>, 100> but I couldn't compile it after I #include <array>. It confuses me when I declare it in different ways!

Comment: First, get rid of the call to malloc(). Second, a list<T> is a growable list. It starts out as empty, and you add items to it by calling push_back(), insert(), etc. You don't treat it like it's an array by using [] syntax -- it is *not* an array.  Last, typedef struct is a hold-over from 'C'.  Are you learning C or C++?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for clarifying the characteristic of list for me. I am learning C++, and typedef struct is the method my professor taught us..it works on C++ so I didn't go further. Btw, besides `malloc()`, is there anyway that do similar function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can use an ordinary loop.

```
std::pair<int, int> p;

for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < line.size(); i++ )
{
   if ( i & 1 == 0 )
   {
      p.first = line[i] - '0';
   }
   else
   {
      p.second = line[i] - '0';
      poly[0].push_back( new Node { p.first, p.second } );
   }
}
```

Only it is not clear why you defined the list as `std::list<Node *>` instead of `std::list<Node>`
You could write simply

```
      poly[0].push_back( { p.first, p.second } );
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! But one question for how to defined the list. Because my list type is Node and it has two different elements (coef and expo in this case). How should I assign p.first and p.second correspond to coef and expo in terms list?

Comment: @lewis04 I do not understand why you defined list as std::list<Node *> you could define it as std::list<Node> and there would not be the requirement to allocate each node in the heap. I showed you in my post how you could fill the list.